# Matlab - Using 3rd party java classes in Parallel Computing Toolbox

Tags: java, matlab, parallel-processing, mosek

I am using Matlab 2013b and Mosek as an external library to solve demanding integer optimization programs. The problem appears when I try to use the external library together with the Parallel Computing Toolbox. It looks like I do not add the classpath correctly...
This is the error:

> Error using partCorrelationClusteringWithMosek (line 61) An
>   UndefinedFunction error was thrown on the workers for 'Model'.  This
>   might be because the file containing 'Model' is not accessible on the
>   workers.  Use addAttachedFiles(pool, files) to specify the required
>   files to be attached.  See the documentation for
>   'parallel.Pool/addAttachedFiles' for more details.

In general I add the classpath as :

```
javaaddpath('/home/user/mosek/7/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin/mosekmatlab.jar');
```

but how do I do this in the case of the Parallel Computing Toolbox?

Comment: have you tried using addAttachedFiles to attach mosekmatlab.jar to your pool?

Comment: yes, but it did not work

Comment: add the classpath call in startup.m - that should get executed when workers start up.

Comment: I added `path(path, '/home/user/mosek/7/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin/');
javaaddpath('/home/user/mosek/7/tools/platform/linux64x86/bin/mosekmatlab.jar');
`
at /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/toolbox/local/startup.m , /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/toolbox/distcomp/user/poolStartup.m , /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/toolbox/distcomp/user/jobStartup.m and /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/toolbox/distcomp/user/taskStartup.m
but still the same error